# How to extract string presents before comma in php

Tags: php

I want to extract string which presents before comma.
If i have something like this

```
/home/Downloads,
/var/www/,
/root/key
```

Then my output should be like

```
/home/Downloads

/var/www/

/root/key
```

and i want to store the result in an array

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Please post your tried effort.

Comment: are they in a single variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use function str_replace:

Atleast I assume you got only url per string and want the part before the comma: simply remove it.

```
$var = "/home/Downloads,"
$var = str_replace(",", "", $var);
```

But I am not 100% certain if this is what you want...

Maybe you want to extract all urls seperated by comma then use explode()

```
$pieces = explode(",", $var);
foreach($pieces as $url) {
    echo $url . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode`. This will split your string at the commas and put every part as one element in an array:

```
$arr = explode(",", $string);

$first = $arr[0];
$second = $arr[1];
$third = $arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **your output to be like this**: `/home/Downloads /var/www/ /root/key` you could do:

```
 echo implode(" ", explode(",", $paths));
```